# Position the input from above on the svg curve

Tags: javascript, css, html, svg

I want to place the input form element above the center of the svg curve as [shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Beqt2.png)

The curve is specified in the following form

```
<svg width="600" height="80" style="border-style: dashed;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="" style="display: none;">
   <defs>
     <marker id="arrow" markerWidth="10" markerHeight="10" refX="0" refY="3" orient="auto" markerUnits="strokeWidth">
       <path d="M0,0 L0,6 L9,3 z" fill="#f00" />
     </marker>
   </defs>
   <path d="M10 40 Q 95 0 200 40" stroke="black" fill="transparent" marker-end="url(#arrow)"/>
</svg>
```

Is it possible to do it somehow? I'm not interested in so much code, so many ideas how it can be done.

[image]

Comment: Well, if this is a simple quadratic curve then its center is right in the middle. Just put the input and the SVG inside a container and center them horizontally, e.g. with flexbox.

Comment: Input must be bound to a curve. It is assumed that there may be several such svg curves

Answer (score 0):

You could use `getBoundingClientRect` to find the bounding box of the curve and then start from there. I added an `id` to your curve so I could find it easily.

```js
function setInputPosition( curve, input ){

  var bb = curve.getBoundingClientRect();
  
  // Since the DOMRect is relative to the viewport,
  // we need to add the amount scrolled to it if we want to absolute
  // position it on the page.
  // I also added half of the curves width to center it horizontally.
  // I used CSS to then align the input around the point,
  // but obviously you could just do that here as well.
  
  input.style.position = 'absolute';
  input.style.top = bb.top + document.body.scrollTop + 'px';
  input.style.left = bb.left + document.body.scrollLeft + bb.width / 2 + 'px';

}

var curve = document.querySelector( '#myPath' );
var input = document.querySelector( '#myInput' );
  
window.addEventListener( 'resize', () => {
  
  setInputPosition( curve, input );
  
});

setInputPosition( curve, input );
```

```css
input {
  
  transform: translate(-50%,-100%);
  
}
```

```html
<svg width="600" height="80" style="border-style: dashed;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="" style="display: none;">
   <defs>
     <marker id="arrow" markerWidth="10" markerHeight="10" refX="0" refY="3" orient="auto" markerUnits="strokeWidth">
       <path d="M0,0 L0,6 L9,3 z" fill="#f00" />
     </marker>
   </defs>
   <path d="M10 40 Q 95 0 200 40" id="myPath" stroke="black" fill="transparent" marker-end="url(#arrow)"/>
</svg>

<input id="myInput" value="centered above curve" />
```